# Is there a way two tedach 2 classes that use each other's variables in Java?

Tags: java, game-engine

I have this game I am writing in java. I've made a class called Camera, witch holds 2 static ints signifying the camera position. The camera possition is requested each frame in a lot of diffrent places. This position is also modified at times in a few diffrent places. My question is if I can detach the camera class in a way that makes the dependent classes independent and more reusable. I've looked at a few things including listeners, but I am not sure if those are meant for continous data transmision. I would really appreciate a bit of advice.

Edit:

```java
public class Camera{
    static public Vector2 cameraPosition;

    static public Vector2 getCameraPosition(){
        return cameraPosition;
    }
}
```

It's also worth saying that I use a component system and I would wish to avoid passing an new camera argument to the things that need it.

Comment: Don't describe your code. Show us.

Comment: Instead of making static reference to `Camera.xPosition`. You can pass Camera object reference to the classes, either in constructor or via setter methods,  and  then invoke `camera.getXPosition()`. This way you can use these classes with different cameras.

Comment: *"My question is if I can detach the camera class in a way that makes the dependent classes independent and more reusable."* Could you show some use-cases that show the current problems you see and you want to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Listeners should work for this usage. Use a setter of the position (including both static ints). In the setter you can call all listeners you saved in a List. Therefor make an interface for the listeners with one method (both ints are parameters). If you want to create a listener you have to implement the interface to your class and add this class to your list or just create a ‘new instance’ of this interface while adding it.

Let me know if you need a code example. But if you doesn’t know what any of this words mean, you should take a look at this parts of Java.

Comment: How will you set new position from a class without accessing `Camera` class? How can we implement fire position change event with new coordinates in it?

Comment: You're confusing something. Decide whether you want to get away from this class (why?) Or whether you want to execute something on change (and not every frame update). Listeners are there for the second. If you want to set a new position it could look like 'Camera.setPosition(newPosition)'. You can call this from everywhere (including any event). The setPosition method calls all Listeners after execution to 'tell them' that the position has been changed.